# How can I force simpleblobdetection to only search inside a contour area?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, simplecv

I'm working on a project where I want to run simple blob detection, but only on areas **inside** a contour. I know contours can return bounding rectangles or circles, but I don't see how to limit a simple blob detection to the area inside that contour.

Any thoughts? I'm stuck.

Comment: Get the bounding Rect of the desired contour -> Crop your image with the boundingRect -> Apply blob detection.

Comment: The suggestion provided by ZdaR is good to a certain extent. You may have a condition where you may want to keep the entire image and still be able to perform blob detection in that contour area. Check out the answer section. I do not have any characters left to type. :)

Answer (score 0):

What I am trying to say is that, consider you want to perform blob detection for a certain region of interest (ROI) on an image, but you also want to keep the image.

ZdaR's comment helps if you want that ROI area alone.

My suggestion would be:

- Create a binary mask of the contour region you want to perform blob detection on.
- Apply the mask on the image. You should be able to obtain only the
  ROI. Now perform blob detection on it.
- Now the same binary mask and mask the **ROI** for which blobs have been detected with the **original image**.

Comment: Hope you understand. If you don't I'll post another answer with an example too.!!! :)